# Consider a 4 digit PIN. How many times do you have to guess to have 10% chance of finding the correct PIN combination?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We know that we have $4$ digits, and for each digit we have to chose between $10$ characters (from $0$ to $9$ ), and so we have $10 ^ 4 = 10000$ possible combinations. 
But I don't know how to answer the question:
How many times do you have to guess to have $10\%$ chance of finding the correct PIN combination?

Comment: Hint: What is the chance that your first guess is wrong? What is the chance that your second guess is also wrong (assuming you don't guess the same answer once proven wrong)? Third guess? Fourth? And so forth, until you reach $n$ where the probability of your guesses $1$ to $n$ are ALL wrong is equal to or less than $90\%$.

Comment: Is 10000 * 10 / 100 = 1000 so we find that arre the chance of getting it right?

Comment: why should this be correct?

Comment: so i have to find and sum the probability of the combination of being incorrect and the remaining will be the one that I was looking for, so the correct answer sould be : 9! / 10! ?

Comment: I'm with @Math - if you cover 10% of the possible PINs, then you have a 10% that it is one of those, and a 90% chance it was a different one - guessing 0000 - 0999 seems to give you a 10% chance to me

Answer (score 1):

You have to guess $n$ times, where $n$ is the first whole number such that

$$\frac{(9999)_n}{(10000)_n} < \frac{9}{10}$$

Here $(a)_b$ denotes the falling factorial of the whole number $a$.

Comment: Can you please explain in a easy way please?

Comment: Why this is not correct :  
Is 10000 * 10 / 100 = 1000 so we find that arre the chance of getting it right?

Comment: and why Eric put a < sign in the formula , I cannot understand it

Comment: Your expression $\dfrac{(9999)_n}{(10000)_n}$ evaluates to exactly $\dfrac{10000-n}{10000}$. So you get the same answer as I do (or you would if you corrected your < to $\le$).

Comment: @TonyK If i understand the expression of Eric right then it is equal to $\frac{\prod_{i=0}^n 9,999-i}{\prod_{i=0}^n 10,000-i}=\frac{9999-n}{10,000}<0.9$ The result is equal to yours $x>999\Rightarrow x=1,000 \ \checkmark$

Comment: @callculus: the range of those products is $i=0$ to $n-1$, not $i=0$ to $n$ $-$ see e.g. [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html). So my expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple: if you pick $1000$ distinct numbers at random, the chance that the PIN is one of them is exactly $0.1$. So the answer is $1000$.

Comment: The answer isn´t simple as that.

Comment: @callculus: Yes it is. See my comment to Eric Auld's answer.